# Mongodb optimal query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My use case is different. I am trying to map it to user and orders for easy understanding.

I have to get the following for a user

```
    For each department
         For each order type
           delivered count
           unique orders
```

Unique order count means user might have ordered the same product, but that count has to be 1 for the same. I have the background logic and identified via duplicate order ids.

```
db.getCollection('user_orders').aggregate([{"user_id":123},
        {$group: {"_id": {"department":"$department", "order_type":"$order_type"}, 
                  "del_count":{$sum:"$del_count"},
                  "unique_order":{$addToSet:{"unique_order":"$unique_order"}}}},

        {$project: {"_id":0, 
                    "department":"$_id.department",
                    "order_type_name":"$_id.order_type",
                    "unique_order_count": {$size:"$unique_order"}, 
                    "del_count":"$del_count"
                                    }},

         {$group: {"_id":"$department", 
                  order_types: {$addToSet: 
                               {"order_type_name":"$order_type_name",
                                "unique_order_count": "$unique_order_count", 
                                "del_count":"$del_count"
                                        }}}}
        ])
```

Sorry for my query formatting.

This query is working absolutely fine. I added the second grouping to bring the responses together for all order types of the same department.

**Can I do the same in less number of pipelines - efficient ways?**

Comment: Why are you using MongoDB like SQL?

Comment: @Yahya Please help me to understand how is it looking like SQL. It is denormalized structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$project` stage appears to be redundant but it's more refactoring rather than performance improvement. Your simplified pipeline can look like below:

```
db.getCollection('user_orders').aggregate([{$group: {"_id": {"department":"$department", "order_type":"$order_type"}, 
                "del_count":{$sum:"$del_count"},
                "unique_order":{$addToSet:{"unique_order":"$unique_order"}}}},

        {$group: {"_id":"$_id.department", 
                order_types: {$addToSet: 
                            {"order_type_name":"$_id.order_type",
                                "unique_order_count": {$size:"$unique_order"}, 
                                "del_count":"$del_count"
                                        }}}}
        ])
```

Comment: It simplifies the pipeline.